# Infinitive phrase after noun (the ability)

Tags: phrases

"Having or showing the ability **to think of new projects or new ways of doing things** and make them successful".

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enterprising?q=enterprising

Part of the bold phrase (Infinitive) is it adjective phrase of the ability?

Comment: Ys..............

Comment: I do not know, meaning to say I cannot be definite that I am 100% right or even 1% right in this instance. For me "the ability to think of new projects or new ways of doing things and make them successful" is a noun phrase. So is the part "to think of new projects or new ways of doing things and make them successful".

Comment: It answers 'what kind of'  the noun "the ability"

Comment: It's clearly an infinitival clause, so it cannot be an adjective phrase. The clause is functioning as complement of the noun "ability", whose meaning it expands. The expression, "The ability to think of new projects or new ways of doing things ... " is thus a noun phrase headed by the noun "ability" with the infinitival clause as its complement.

Comment: @BillJ
"Find a friend to help you study. What is it "to help...."? and "This is a good place to start reading.” what is it "to start reading"? both describe the noun that it come after. Similarly To think... describe the noun 'ability'.

Comment: What is difference between modify and complement? both describe the noun in that way that adjective phrase do.

Comment: @BillJ
 The infinitive clause describes the noun "the ability'. that is the reason  I said did it work adjectivally. Modify- it describe or elaborate upon and complement- complete the meaning of the word in sentence. Yes, I did little research before posting.

Comment: You're mixing up the terms 'adjectivally' and 'modifier'. As I've already told you, adjective is a part of speech, while modifier is a function. Not all adjective phrases are modifiers; they may also be complements. For example "Ed is a **nice** guy"(modifier) ~ "Ed was **nice**" (complement).

Answer (score 2):

*Ability* is a noun formed from *able*; if you have an ability, you are able to do something. *Be able to* is a [periphrastic modal auxiliary](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/474969/15299); it means the same as *can*:

- *Is he able **to** do that?*
- *Yes, he can certainly do that.*

And, like all modals, it takes an infinitive complement, with the infinitive *to* complementizer in these periphrastic cases.

Nouns like *ability* that are formed from predicates like *able* that
take infinitive complements can also take infinitive complements, like *(to) run a mile in 5 minutes* below:

- *He can **run a mile in 5 minutes**.*
- *He is able **to run a mile in 5 minutes***.
- *He has the ability **to run a mile in 5 minutes**.*

So the boldfaced infinitive clause below

- *the ability **to think of stuff***

is the complement clause of *ability*, because it's the infinitive complement of *be able*, which means *can*.

Normally only nouns that come from verbs that take complements can take complements themselves; NP complements can be non-finite, like this infinitive, or they can be tensed, like the *that*-clause complement of *the report* (because the verb *to report* takes a *that*-clause complement):

- *the report **that she shot him twice***
- *they reported **that she shot him twice***

Comment: Interesting. But how does it explain the acceptability of "It provides an [opportunity to broaden the mind]"?

Comment: The _it_ is referential, if that's what you're asking about. As for _opportunity_, it does take an infinitive complement, and there doesn't appear to be a verb that it's derived from. A hole in the fabric; who would have suspected it? Perhaps not all rules are totally regular.

Comment: The second bit. I too spotted "the hole in the fabric", as you put it. Damned grammar of ours!